# Creation of a temp file on Windows

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception-handling, file, windows

I implemented a test that reads data from temp file on Windows. 
I originally had an issue that I solved with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9155528/230717)

```py
def test_read(self):
    """Test read from file"""
    import tempfile
    import os
    try:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp:
            content = 'Some data'
            temp.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
            temp.flush()
            self.assertEqual(content, b.read(Path(temp.name)))
    finally:
        os.remove(temp.name)
```

How can I do this better? 
Is it ok to have `try...finally` in the test?

`b` is a custom module.
It reads data from temp file.

```py
def read(path):
    """Reads file content from FS"""
    if path in VIRTUAL_FS:
       return VIRTUAL_FS[path]
    with open(path.as_posix(), 'r') as file:
       return file.read()
```

Comment: What is `b`? What is the purpose of this test?

Comment: Purpose that b reads data from file properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `try` block, `temp` might not get assigned, so `temp.name` would be an error. But this is an extremely unlikely scenario.

You seem to be going out of your way to defeat the natural clean-up capability of the [named temporary file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile):

> If *`delete`* is true (the default), the file is deleted as soon as it is closed.

Since the file is opened via a `with` block, it should be closed automatically at the end of the block, and automatically deleted as well, if you let it.  Therefore, you shouldn't need the `try...finally` at all, and you can remove the `delete=False` parameter from `NamedTemporaryFile`:

```
def test_read(self):
    """Test read from file"""
    import tempfile

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
        content = 'Some data'
        temp.write(content.encode('utf-8'))
        temp.flush()
        self.assertEqual(content, b.read(Path(temp.name)))
```

When you open a file for reading, you can omit the `r` in here:

> ```
> with open(path.as_posix(), 'r') as file:
>    return file.read()
> ```

Finally, `b` is terrible name. It doesn't tell anything about the module.

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know the default `mode` for `open` function. On the other hand if I would remove the `delete=False` and run it on Windows, I get `permission denied IOError` as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/94153/2517622).